# Diferença na alocação dinâmica de memória na função principal vs. em uma função void

Tags: c, alocação, vector, malloc

Estou conseguindo utilizar a função malloc/realloc para alocar memória para um vetor de números inteiros na main

**Está Funcionando:**

```
int main () {
    int resultSize = 0;
    int *result = NULL;

    result = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * (resultSize + 1));
    result[resultSize++] = 20;
    printf("%d\n", result[resultSize - 1]);

    result = (int*) realloc(result, sizeof(int) * (resultSize + 1));
    result[resultSize++] = 40;
    printf("%d\n", result[resultSize - 1]);

    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Entretanto, quanto tento fazer essa alocação dentro de uma outra função **não funciona**:

```
void atribuirValoresVetor(int *result, int resultSize) {
    result = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * (resultSize + 1));

    result[resultSize++] = 20; 

    result = (int*) realloc(result, sizeof(int) * (resultSize + 1));
    result[resultSize++] = 40;
}

int main () {
    int resultSize = 0;
    int *result = NULL;

    atribuirValoresVetor(result, resultSize);

    printf("%d\n", result[0]);
    printf("%d\n", result[1]);

    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Obs.: Para esta função eu não posso utilizar ponteiros de ponteiros (int **result);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um ponteiro nada mais é que um valor. Nesse sentido, um `void*` é valor tal como, por exemplo, um `int`. Claro que o tamanho do valor pode ser diferente a depender do tipo, mas isso não vem ao caso.

Por conta disso, quando você passa um ponteiro como argumento para uma função, ele é *copiado*. Sobre o valor apontado, obviamente, não há cópia.

Essa semântica, evidentemente, atrapalha o que você quer fazer. Repare que a sua função `atribuirValoresVetor` *modifica* a variável `result` (primeiro parâmetro da função). No entanto, como trata-se de uma *cópia*, essa mudança limitar-se-á à própria função `atribuirValoresVetor`.

Um exemplo mais simples para facilitar a compreensão do problema. Se fizermos:

```
void modify_param(int a) {
  a = 0;
}

int a = 1;
modify_param(a);
printf("%d", a); //=> "1"
```

Repare que, quando a função modifica um parâmetro (passado por valor – tal como, nesse exemplo, o inteiro ou, no exemplo anterior, o ponteiro), não há reflexão na variável da função chamadora. O que foi modificado é a cópia.

Tanto é que, para modificar uma variável da função chamadora, precisamos utilizar um ponteiro. Desse modo, podemos, da função chamadora, desreferenciar o ponteiro e modificar a variável apontada diretamente. Nesse caso, não estamos modificando o ponteiro em si, mas sim a variável que é apontada.

Tentei ser bem enfático acima. Com tudo isso deve ser simples entender que, nesse caso, como precisamos modificar o próprio ponteiro, é ideal utilizar um *ponteiro de ponteiro* para resolver esse problema. Nesse caso, você faz apenas uma desreferenciação e modifica o ponteiro interno.

Um exemplo que, embora simples e provavelmente inútil, demonstra isso:

```
void useless_realloc(int** arr, int size) {
  int* new_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
  // Omiti a parte de copiar os elementos de um array para o outro...
  free(*arr);
  *arr = new_ptr;
}

int main() {
  int cap = 10;
  int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * cap);

  // E, na chamada, passar um ponteiro ao ponteiro:
  useless_realloc(&arr, ...);

  free(arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Claro que, se por algum motivo (talvez requerimento de exercício) utilizar ponteiro de ponteiro não for possível, pode-se *retornar*, da função, o novo ponteiro. Assim:

```
int* useless_realloc(int* arr, int size) {
  int* new_ptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
  // Omiti a parte de copiar os elementos de um array para o outro...
  free(arr);
  return new_ptr;
}

int main() {
  int cap = 10;
  int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * cap);

  // E na chamada, modificar o ponteiro:
  arr = useless_realloc(arr, cap);

  free(arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Claro que, nesse caso, usar um ponteiro de ponteiro, apesar da indireção adicional, parece-me mais simples.

Comment: Olá Luiz Felipe, agradeço pela resposta. Realmente eu pensei nessa solução de retornar um ponteiro ou então utilizar ponteiros de ponteiros como parâmetro para a função. Entretanto, estou limitado a este exemplo, passando apenas um ponteiro simples como parâmetro de função.

Comment: Talvez seja de fato  essa a resolução deste problema que me foi proposto, não ter resolução correta e apontar os erros.

Comment: É, se não pode nenhum dos dois e precisa de ser em outra função, não vejo outra solução — senão, claro, colocar tudo na mesma função. Todavia esse requerimento me parece bem estranho.

Comment: Quantos jeitos existem em C para declarar um parâmetro que deve receber um array ou coisa semelhante, eu pergunto a vocês? É o que posso dar de dica, dentro do que acho que resolveria o problema. Pessoalmente acho que a pergunta é imprópria, porque está beirando muito o "resolvam para mim". P.S.: Bem sacado o retornar ponteiro, não cheguei a pensar nisso.

Comment: @Piovezan, conheço pouco de C, então pelo que sei, não consigo responder. Todavia aceito mais comentários. :-)

Comment: @Piovezan talvez eu não tenha feito a pergunta da forma correta, de maneira alguma eu quero que resolvam para mim o problema, tanto que omiti 99% do problema que tenho para resolver. A questão é que eu consegui redimensionar o tamanho do vetor no escopo em que ele foi declarado, mas quando eu passo ele para uma determinada função, eu consigo redimensiona-lo apenas para o escopo da função em si, o que da a entender que estou passando apenas uma cópia do vetor para a função. Infelizmente eu não posso modificar essa questão (substituir int *result por int **result ou retornar um ponteiro).

Comment: Por isso a minha dúvida: da para redimensionar o tamanho do vetor original por meio da passagem (int *result)?

Comment: Se a questão tem a restrição de não permitir a forma "simples" de resolver (com `int **result`), então eu entendo que ela deva ser resolvida de forma mais complicada, e que esse é o grande ponto da questão. Isso por si só já dá uma boa questão envolvendo sintaxe do C. Por isso achei por bem dar apenas uma dica (quantas formas a sintaxe permite de se declarar que um parâmetro de função deve receber um array ou coisa semelhante) e não entrar em mais detalhes. Além disso, a dica que pode ser dada é que usando indireção simples não tem como resolver, sem ser via retorno da função.

Comment: P.S.: Acho que estou falando besteira. Tenha em mente que um array é um espaço de elementos contíguos de mesmo tipo, alocado numa posição fixa da memória, e a variável apontando para esse array guarda o endereço do primeiro elemento localizado no início do espaço alocado. Se você declara por exemplo `int arr[] = malloc(...)` e passa para uma função `realoca(arr)` que tiver sido declarada `void realoca(int *arr) { ... }`, acredito que dê para dar outro `malloc` nesse mesmo endereço (um `realloc` no caso, pois `malloc` necessariamente vai criar espaço novo caso seja bem-sucedido) e...

Comment: ...e isso irá se refletir na variável passada como argumento para a função, fora da função. Questão de testar.

Comment: P.S.2: Havia ficado curioso sobre o assunto e fiz [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/528366/357), e de acordo com ela não existe garantia que o que eu falei dê certo. Ao que parece a linguagem C tem uma tendência de tratar arrays como espaços a serem alocados e desalocados, mas não necessariamente redimensionados no lugar em que estão. E a propósito, faltou um _cast_ no malloc que citei de exemplo dois comentários acima.

Comment: O problema não faz o menor sentido, mas se for necessário manter a assinatura da função a qualquer custo, é possível fazer uma gambiarra usando variável global. cf. https://ideone.com/423bFS . Quanto a solução, é óbvio que com uma global você não precisa passar `result` como argumento e nem usar o *ugly hack* com o `extern`, mas aí a assinatura da função teria que ser alterada para remover o `result` é coisa que aparentemente o problema não permite.

Comment: Outra solução possível poderia se basear no fato de que em C sempre é possível converter um ponteiro em outro tipo de ponteiro desde que seja utilizado o tipo correto no momento de derrefenciar, cf. https://ideone.com/9wGyor . Mas aqui, na prática, faz-se uso de ponteiro para ponteiro, embora não de forma muito explicita.

Comment: Em tempo, me parece que um _cast_ no retorno de `malloc()` [não é necessário](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2241463).